# How can i fit images in to div ( Ionic )

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, sass, ionic4

I have a div container and inside of div i have a img.

```
  <div  style="background-color: red; height: 200px; width: 200px;">
    <ion-img  src="{{kategori[i].img}}"></ion-img>

    </div>
```

I want to fill that div with my image. But its not fit inside. Its looks like that :

https://prnt.sc/12qcj8h

Some of them being small some of them being big. How can i fill inside of div ? I dont want see red background and i want it fill inside of div. Its my css code :

```
ion-img {

  border-radius: 15px;
  background-size: cover;
  max-width: 100% !important;
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ion-img {
  border-radius: 15px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp

Answer (score 0):

try this `<div  style="display: flex; background-color: red; height: 200px; width: 200px; object-fit: cover;">`

remove object-fit:cover from image style

`ion-img { border-radius: 15px; }`